# Paso de variables desde javascript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, variables

Tengo dos variables declaradas asi

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){

        var extensionesValidas = ".pdf, .PDF";
        var tamanioPermitido = 256;
        
    $("#archivo").change(function () {
     // Aquí mas código y funciones.. donde utilizo estas variables y me funcionan las validaciones sin problema.
   }     
});
```

Pero ocupo que extensionesValidas y tamanioPermitido las pueda recuperar en un archivo PHP para validar el tamaño y tipo de extensión de un archivo a subir,  ¿como podría pasar esos dos valores al archivo PHP ? Solo necesito recibirlas en el PHP.
Gracias

Saludos

Gracias

Comment: La comunicación entre PHP y JS comunmente se realiza con AJAX

Comment: Ok entonces tendría que pasar esos valores directamente al archivo PHP con AJAX ? al momento que se haga clic en el <input type="file" name="archivo"  required accept="application/pdf" id="archivo"">   o se puede hacer que se haga la carga en "automatico" desde que carga el script donde se encuentran las variables definidas ?...

Comment: No es recomendable enviar esos parámetros desde el cliente, se pueden modificar fácilmente, pero, si quieres seguir por ahí, necesitas enviarlas al momento de procesar el formulario, ya sea como campos ocultos o datos si lo envías por AJAX.

Comment: @Triby ok gracias, si ya estamos viendo otra opción, jaja todo lo que hice que siempre no. Panza Verde te dice algo ?

Comment: Excelente, haz lo posible por minimizar riesgos de seguridad. Por supuesto, soy fiera de hueso colorado.

Comment: @Triby tu sabes como se usa este codigo:   peticion.send(JSON.stringify({
        tamanio: "2000",
        extension: "xls"
    }));  quiero recuperar los valores entre comillas en PHP .

Comment: Depende del método (get o post), puede ser `$_GET['tamanio']` o `$_POST['tamanio']` y, menos recomendable, `$_REQUEST['tamanio']`.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115110/discussion-between-cesarin-and-triby).